# Birthday paradox with a twist

Tags: probability-theory, birthday

My questin is a variation on the birthday paradox problem:

[image]

The difference being that here we want to know if two people have the same *given* birthday, not *any* same birthday. How would I solve this?

Comment: Well, it's easier to compute the probability that none of the $N$ are born on the chosen day, or that exactly one of the $N$ people were born on that day.

Answer (score 1):

If you have n people, the possibility that no person is born on the 24th of december is $P_0=\frac{365}{366}^{n}$. The possibility that exactly one person is born on the 24th of december is $P_1=\frac{365}{366}^{n-1}\times \frac{1}{366}\times n$. Therefore the possibility that two or more people are born on the 24th of december is $P_{\geq2}=1-P_0-P_1$. From this you can solve for the minimum amount of people needed.

Comment: Are you sure about the $n$ in $P_1$?

Comment: For each individual, the probability that he is the only one born on the 24th is $\frac{365}{366}^{n-1}\times \frac{1}{366}$. There are n individuals, therefore we have to multiply this probability by n.